# transition matrix for counts and proportions python

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, transition, markov

I have a matrix with the grades from a class for different years(rows for years and columns for grades).
What I want is to build a transition matrix with the change between years.

For instance, I want year t-1 on the y-axis and year t on the x-axis and then I want a transition matrix with the difference in the number of people with grade A between year t-1 and t, grade B between year t-1 and t, and so on. 
And then a second transition matrix with the proportions, for example:
- Between year t-1 and t there z% more/less people with grade A/B/C/D/F.

Obviously the moest import part is the diagonal which would represent the change for the same grade for different years.

I want this to be done in Python.

Thank you very much, I hope everything is clear.

Result example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joh3O.png)

Comment: I'm not quite sure of how you want your transition matrix. Can you make an example with a small matrix? And do you want to use numpy matrix?

Comment: are grades represented as number of A, B, C's, etc.?

Comment: Hello @BaptisteMerliot , just added an example of result

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti  , yes the numbers are the counts for how many people had A, B, C, ....

Comment: So in your example, you have like 50 less A grade in 2017 than in 2016, and 30 B grade in more in 2017 than A grade in 2016, etc... ?

Comment: exactly @BaptisteMerliot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas library with `df.diff`. numpy can generate the matrix of all possible differences using `np.subtract.outer`. below is an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']
grades = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4)), columns=grades, index=years)

print(df)

      A  B  C  D
2015  5  0  2  0
2016  7  2  0  2
2017  3  7  6  7

df_diff = df.diff(axis=0)
print(df_diff)
```

each row here in `df_diff` is the difference between current row and the preceding one from original df

```
        A        B     C     D
2015    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
2016    2.0     2.0   -2.0  2.0
2017    -4.0    5.0   6.0   5.0

a = np.array([])
differences = []
for i, y in enumerate(years):
    for j, g in enumerate(grades):
        differences.append(y+g)
        a = np.append(a, df.iloc[i,j])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(a, a), columns=differences, index=differences)
print(df3)

      2015A   2015B  2015C  2015D   2016A   2016B   2016C   2016D   2017A   2017B   2017C   2017D
2015A   0.0     5.0  3.0    5.0 -2.0    3.0     5.0 3.0      2.0    -2.0    -1.0    -2.0
2015B   -5.0    0.0 -2.0    0.0 -7.0    -2.0    0.0 -2.0    -3.0    -7.0    -6.0    -7.0
2015C   -3.0    2.0  0.0    2.0 -5.0    0.0     2.0 0.0     -1.0    -5.0    -4.0    -5.0
2015D   -5.0    0.0 -2.0    0.0 -7.0    -2.0    0.0 -2.0    -3.0    -7.0    -6.0    -7.0
2016A   2.0     7.0 5.0     7.0  0.0    5.0     7.0  5.0    4.0     0.0   1.0       0.0
2016B   -3.0    2.0 0.0     2.0 -5.0    0.0     2.0 0.0    -1.0    -5.0  -4.0   -5.0
2016C   -5.0    0.0 -2.0    0.0 -7.0    -2.0    0.0 -2.0   -3.0    -7.0  -6.0   -7.0
2016D   -3.0    2.0 0.0     2.0 -5.0    0.0     2.0 0.0    -1.0     -5.0    -4.0    -5.0
2017A   -2.0    3.0 1.0     3.0 -4.0    1.0     3.0 1.0     0.0    -4.0  -3.0   -4.0
2017B   2.0     7.0 5.0     7.0 0.0     5.0     7.0 5.0     4.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
2017C   1.0     6.0 4.0     6.0 -1.0    4.0     6.0 4.0     3.0    -1.0   0.0     -1.0
2017D   2.0     7.0 5.0     7.0 0.0     5.0     7.0 5.0     4.0     0.0   1.0 0.0
```

plot this matrix using `matshow` from `matplotlib`

```
plt.matshow(df3)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]